# Detecting recursive calls

Tags: ruby, recursion

What is the best way to detect recursive method calls? Perhaps, it can be made into this format:

```
def foo
  if some_code_to_detect_recursive_call
    ...
  else
    ...
  end
end
```

I can think of a way parsing the `caller` information, but I am interested in seeing if there are better ways.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just increment a counter (an instance or global variable) after entry to your method and decrement it on exit.

At entry, the counter tells you your recursion level.

Answer (score 1):

```rb
def is_recursive(max_recursive_calls=2)
  calls = caller.inject(0) do |calls, line|
    break calls if calls >= max_recursive_calls
    calls += 1 if line == caller[-2]
    calls
  end
  calls >= max_recursive_calls
end
```

#### Test cases:

```rb
# 1
def recursive
  p "case #1"
  recursive unless is_recursive
end

# 2
def recursive_a
  p "case #2.1"
  recursive_b unless is_recursive
end

def recursive_b
  p "case #2.2"
  recursive_a unless is_recursive
end

# 3
def recursive_cond(iter=0, limit=10)
  p "case #3"
  recursive_cond(iter + 1, limit) unless iter > limit || is_recursive(50)
end

recursive
recursive_a
recursive_b
recursive_cond

p "If you see this: is_recursive function implemented correctly"
```

#### Output

```rb
"case #1"
"case #1"
"case #2.1"
"case #2.2"
"case #2.1"
"case #2.2"
"case #2.1"
"case #2.2"
"case #3"
"case #3"
"case #3"
"case #3"
"case #3"
"case #3"
"case #3"
"case #3"
"case #3"
"case #3"
"case #3"
"case #3"
"If you see this: is_recursive function implemented correctly"
```